# Onepage checkout tab rearranging

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

In one page checkout we have a sequence for the tab. I changed the sequence by overwriting the block

```
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage>Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block_Onepage</onepage>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
```

onepage.php as below

```
<?php
class Ucs_OneStepCheckout_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
    public function getSteps()
    {
        $steps = array();

        if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $steps['login'] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData('login');
        }

        $stepCodes = array('review', 'billing', 'shipping');

        foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
            $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
        }
        return $steps;
    }

}
```

If I rearrange any other tab as first than review it is working fine, but if arrange review tab as first, still billing tab is getting loaded.

How can I show the review step as first step, then billing shipping?

Comment: I believe review should be at the end, just before submitting the order. Why do you want to put it at first?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri assume if I fill all info and come to review, by mistake I added the 150ml product instead of 250ml. now all the entered info go fail, I have to review first then place order.

Comment: I see, in that case, customer can review in cart page. However, I do understand your point.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri one more idea is my checkout page will have only review section no payment shipping nothing.. This is only for our internal organization. address is predefined for each user. So they can just review and place order. I posted other question too http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82190/onepage-checkout-tab-rearranging?noredirect=1